# Вопрос про has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Есть 2 модели: `Item` и `Category`, связь `has_and_belongs_to_many`.
Как при создании нового `Item` присвоить ему Категорию?

```
#items_controller.rb

def create
  item = Item.create(params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :cost, :category))
end
```

Выдает ошибку..

Comment: @zzex, добавьте пожалуйста текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все разобрался. надо оказывается использовать :category_ids. Вопрос можно удалить если некому не понадобиться